# MatRipple Continues To Show No Matter What

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a very limited space around the `mat-radio-button` element so I wanted to disable it. It is half disabled but, on `hover` action, it's "ghost" continues to show on `hover`like below;

[image: on hover]

This is my `mat-radio-button`;

```
<mat-radio-button  [disableRipple]="true" [checked]="element == expandedElement"(change)="ShowDetail(element)" ></mat-radio-button>
```

And to be clear, `[disableRipple]` disables the effect that shows on `onclick` but not the effect on `hover`. Anybody have a solution that might help me?

This is what I've tried but doesn't work which is located at the `styles.css` of the component (When doing `document.querySelectorAll()` this gives the ghost part);

```
span.mat-ripple-element.mat-radio-persistent-ripple{
  display: none !important;
}
```

Stakblitz that shows `disableRipple` only removes the ripple that is shown on `onlick` event : [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehgpd2?file=src/app/form-field-label-example.css) (Auto is the one with `disableRipple` attribute)

Comment: could you please share a workable demo on stackblitz? That's be really helpful :)

Comment: Ripple comes into picture only when you click the button not on hover.

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz I edited the question with a stackblitz example

Comment: @Vimal Patel it is not the case unfortunately :\

Comment: @oividiosCaeremos your stackblitz example not working.

Comment: @VimalPatel sorry, I accidently put the wrong one.

Comment: [disableRipple]="true"  is working fine [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehgpd2-wjtrxk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-label-example.html)

Comment: @VimalPatel if you hover, there's still a circle around the radiobutton though.

Comment: so you want to get rid of that hover?

Comment: @VimalPatel Yes, I do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To remove the ripple effect you can just add the following to your styles.scss file:

```
.mat-radio-ripple {
  display: none;
}
```

As you can see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ehgpd2-2hvt7s?file=src/styles.scss

This removes the ripple to the material radio buttons.

To remove it for all mat elements you can just do:

```
.mat-ripple { display: none; }
```

To remove if just for checkboxes:

```
.mat-checkbox-ripple { display: none; }
```

etc...

As you can see here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17404

(Also please note that as mentioned in the guthub issue the ripples on focus/click are there for accessibility, that's the reason why they're difficult to get rid of, I think you should keep that in mind and do something on a mat radio that if active or has focus)

Comment: Seni seviyorum Dario <3

Answer (score 0):

To remove the background color on hover. Add below css in your style.css/style.scss file.

```
.mat-radio-container:hover .mat-radio-persistent-ripple {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vimal Patel, `...And to be clear, [disableRipple] disables the effect that shows on onclick but not the effect on hover...` I don't think the question is wrong or needs update, but thank you for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me

```scss
::ng-deep {
  .mat-mdc-button-ripple,
  .mdc-button__ripple {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```